# Case split on a maybe type on PureScript

Tags: purescript

I am learning PureScript by following [PureScript by example](https://book.purescript.org/chapter3.html#functions-and-records), and by chapter 3 (rest of definitions there) there is an exercise to delete duplicate entries from a bog, but I cannot get to work the case split for the Maybe (Nothing/Just e). I checked also [the syntax guide](https://github.com/purescript/documentation/blob/master/language/Syntax.md) but I cannot catch the pitfall and keep getting `Unknown data constructor Nothing`.

```
import Prelude    
import Data.AddressBook
import Control.Plus (empty)
import Data.List (List(..), (:), filter, head, foldl, tail)
import Data.Maybe (Maybe, isJust)
import Data.Newtype (overF)

skipIfDup :: AddressBook -> AddressBook -> AddressBook
skipIfDup newBook (Nil : book) = newBook
skipIfDup newBook (entry : book) =
    skipIfDup newerBook book
    where
        newerBook :: AddressBook
        newerBook = 
            case findEntry entry.firstName entry.lastName newerBook of
                Nothing -> newBook
                Just e -> insertEntry e newBook
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Unknown data constructor Nothing" means just what it says: the compiler doesn't know what `Nothing` is, where it's defined.

And how do you let it know where it's defined? Same way as with all the other stuff you're using in your program - with an `import`!

You already have `import Data.Maybe (Maybe)`, but that's not enough: this is importing only the type `Maybe`, but not its constructors.

To import the `Nothing` constructor, add it after the type in parens like this:

```
import Data.Maybe (Maybe(Nothing), isJust)
```

Or you can import all constructors that exist by using two dots instead:

```
import Data.Maybe (Maybe(..), isJust)
```

The latter is the more accepted pattern.

Comment: that was the answer. having imported Maybe already and not being possible to import "Nothing" as a symbol I was getting crazy.