# How to match empty List type wrapper type on signature. Against type signature the function returns Nil

Tags: purescript

Still regarding chapter 3 of "PureScript by example" (non-related [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67939010/case-split-on-a-maybe-type-on-purescript)). The function `removeDuplicates` returns me Nil on test and on the repl returns Nil rather than AddressBook which is a bit disappointing as I was expecting the compiler to prevent such case. In the other hand I also seem to fail to match an empty AddressBook (`type AddressBook = List Entry`).

Code (simplified omitting irrelevant parts):

```
emptyBook :: AddressBook
emptyBook = empty

findEntry :: String -> String -> AddressBook -> Maybe Entry
findEntry firstName lastName = head <<< filter filterEntry
  where
  filterEntry :: Entry -> Boolean
  filterEntry entry = entry.firstName == firstName && entry.lastName == lastName

-- implementation which fails test/breaks compiler warranty

import Data.AddressBook
import Prelude

import Control.Plus (empty)
import Data.List (List(..), filter, foldl, head, null, tail, (:))


removeDuplicates :: AddressBook -> AddressBook
removeDuplicates book = skipIfDup emptyBook book

skipIfDup :: AddressBook -> AddressBook -> AddressBook
skipIfDup newBook Nil = newBook
skipIfDup newBook (entry : book) =
    skipIfDup newerBook book
    where
    newerBook :: AddressBook
    newerBook = 
        case (findEntry entry.firstName entry.lastName newBook) of
            Nothing -> newBook
            Just e -> insertEntry e newBook
```

In addition to `Nil`, I tried `Data.List.null` and `emptyBook` (but I believe the symbol gets rebounded) with the same results. Using `[]` does not compile, and bringing the case to an if-else statement to the main case, but then the compiler complains about not converting the Nil use case.

What is going on? Why does the compiler allow a Nil returning function? How should I properly test the use case of an empty List/AddressBook by using `null` or whatever necessary symbol?

REPL output:

```
> removeDuplicates book with duplicate
Nil
```

Test case Output:

```
☠ Failed: Exercise - removeDuplicates because expected ({ address: { city: "Faketown", state: "CA", street: "123 Fake St." }, firstName: "John", lastName: "Smith" } : { address: { city: "Arlen", state: "TX", street: "84 Rainey St." }, firstName: "Peggy", lastName: "Hill" } : { address: { city: "Springfield", state: "USA", street: "740 Evergreen Terrace" }, firstName: "Ned", lastName: "Flanders" } : Nil), got Nil
```

Comment: Why would you expect the compiler to prevent returning `Nil`? You have `AddressBook` defined as an alias for `List`, and `Nil` is a perfectly valid value for it.

Comment: Now I got to understand that `Nil` is the actual representation of an empty list rather than an out of domain value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike C# or JavaScript, or wherever it is you're coming from, `Nil` and `null` in PureScript are not a special/magic "uninitialized reference" sort of thing. PureScript doesn't have those at all. Everything is always "defined", as far as the PureScript compiler knows.

`Nil` is just the name of a `List` constructor. Take a look at [the `List` definition](https://github.com/purescript/purescript-lists/blob/v6.0.1/src/Data/List/Types.purs#L36-L36):

```
data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a)
```

It's just a sum type with two constructors, one of them named `Nil`. Could be named `Abracadabra` and still work the same, but apparently the library authors wanted names to mean something, I guess? Silly people. So `Nil` in this case is supposed to mean "empty list".

Similarly, `null` is just a function name. [Here's its definition](https://github.com/purescript/purescript-lists/blob/v6.0.1/src/Data/List.purs#L190-L190):

```
null :: forall a. List a -> Boolean
null Nil = true
null _ = false
```

It just returns `true` is the given list is an empty one, and `false` otherwise.

---

Now, the actual problem in your case lies here:

```
    newerBook = 
        case (findEntry entry.firstName entry.lastName newBook) of
            Nothing -> newBook
            Just e -> insertEntry e newBook
```

Look what you're doing: you try to find the entry in `newBook`, and if found, you insert that same entry right back into `newBook`. So that `newBook` would now have two such entries. Is that really what you meant to do?

From my vague understanding of the original problem, what you really want to do is to add the `entry` to `newBook` if it's *not* in there already. And if it *is* in there, leave `newBook` alone:

```
    newerBook = 
        case (findEntry entry.firstName entry.lastName newBook) of
            Nothing -> entry : newBook
            Just _ -> newBook
```

Comment: I failed to see that `emptyBook` is actually represented as `Nil`, even on the REPL, and I automatically thought the faulty situation was caused by the compiler `> emptyBook Nil`